# Need help building complex multi-table queries

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, bioinformatics

**This question is something that a lot of people learning bioinformatics and new to DNA data analysis are struggling with:**

Lets say I have 20 tables with the same column headings. Each table represents a patient sample and each row represents a locus (site) which has mutated in that sample. Each site is uniquely identified by two columns together - chromosome number and base number (eg. 1 and 43535, 1 and 33456, 1 and 3454353). There are several columns which give different characteristics of each mutation including a column called Gene which gives the gene at that site.. Multiple sites can be mutated in a gene - meaning the Gene column can have the same value multiple times in one table.

I want to **query all these tables at the same time** by lets say Gene. I input a value from the Gene column and I want as output the names of all the tables (samples) in which the gene name is present in the Gene column and also the entire line(s) (preferably) for each sample so that I can compare the characteristics of the mutation in that gene across multiple samples on one output page.

I also want to input a number say 4 and want as output a list of genes which have mutated in at least 4 of 20 patients (list of genes whose names appear in the Gene column in atleast 4 of 20 tables).

What is the "easiest way" to do this? What is the "best way" assuming I want to make more flexible queries, besides these two?

I am a MD, do not have any particular software expertise but I am willing to put in the necessary time to build this query system. A few lines of code won't put me off..

Eg data:

```
Func    Gene    ExonicFunc                 Chr  Start       End        Ref  Obs
exonic  ACTRT2  nonsynonymous SNV           1   2939346     2939346     G   A
exonic  EIF4G3  nonsynonymous SNV           1   21226201    21226201    G   A
exonic  CSMD2   nonsynonymous SNV           1   34123714    34123714    C   T
```

This is just a third of the columns. Multiple columns were removed to fit the page size here...

Thank you.

Comment: Post table definition (CREATE TABLE code or if that's not available, columns, datatypes and keys). Add (if possible) a few rows of data.

Comment: Using sub-queries for each table would probably be **easiest**. If possible, I would recommend an EAV setup for medical applications.

Comment: Just to clarify, you say you have 20 tables with the same column headings. Do you mean you have twenty different entries(rows) in one table? I read that you aren't familiar with databases, but should I assume that by twenty different tables, you mean twenty different records in one table?

Comment: Is this a data structure you have or trying to design? Pulling the table name as a value is not something you would normally try to do (though that information is available in system tables for real database systems)

Comment: @Scott: I have 20 tables, not 20 rows! Each table has a average of 500 records.. 500 mutations in each patient..

Comment: @Limey : I am in the process of generating these 20 tables through processing DNA sequences. So at the end of it, I will have 20 excel files and a huge amount of information..

Comment: @ypercube : Few rows of data posted from one table..

Comment: @njk Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user1480585:  it realy sounds like you need to simplify.  Instead of 20 seperate tables, it sounds like you need one with an extra column defining which sample the Row belongs to.

Comment: Subquery meaning you would select each column from each table into one table with 20 columns. See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2110957/ for EAV model.

Comment: @Limey : Thats easy enough. Can copy,paste and build a file like that in 10 min? Whats after?

Comment: for a non programmer suh as yourself, i would just use the built  in filtering functions of Excel to get the information you are looking for (Select "Filter" in the "Data" menu of Excel).

Comment: @Limey : Well, I considered that before. Excel has its limitations. I cannot do the second type of query I described, for example..

Comment: @Shyam_LA:  Yes you can.  you need to look at using the count ans sum functions to get the counts you need.  this should start you in the right direction:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Comment: @Limey : I am not sure I follow. I don't want to count. I want to give a count and get names that are present in at least as many samples. Refer: answer from SQLcurious below. Can that be done in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you have is a bunch of Excel files, *you can import them all into the same table*, with a distinct column for patient id. There is no need to create 20 different tables for this -- in fact, it would be a bad idea.

Once you do, go to Access' query design, SQL view and use these queries:

To create a query that returns all fields for the input gene name:

```
select *
from gene_data
where gene = [GeneName]
```

To create a query that returns gene names that are mutated in more than 4 samples:

```
select gene
from
(select gene, sample_id
from gene_data
group by gene, sample_id) g
group by gene
having count(sample_id) > 4
```

After this, change to design view -- you'll see how to create similar queries using the GUI.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like something I can work with.. But I want to return genes that are mutated in 4 samples. That is listed under the Gene column in 4 of the original tables, which I have now amalgamated into one table with a new column for sample number.. How should I do that?

Comment: To create a query that returns all fields for the input gene name:

select *
from gene
where gene_name = [GeneName]

Can you please use examples from the eg. data above? Thats sort of confusing. I don't understand what gene, gene_name and GeneName in your code represent. Thank you..

Comment: I've edited my queries. As they stand now, gene_data = table name, gene = gene name field, [GeneName] = parameter defined within query that holds user input.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The first query works perfectly. Will try the second one in a few minutes. I'm sure it will work too..

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that union's all the tables together.  You should probably add additional information about which table ti comes from:

```
create view allpatients as
    select 'a' as whichtable, t.*
    from tableA t
    union all
    select 'b' as whichtable, t.*
    from tableB t
    ...
```

You might find that it is easier to "instantiate" the view by creating a table with all patients.  Just have a stored procedure that recreates the table by combining the 20 tables.

Alternatively, you could find that you have large individual tables (millions of rows).  In this case, you would want to treat each of the original tables as a partition.